# Is there a standard way to implement enterprise managed app configuration in Android?

Tags: android, standards, enterprise

I know iOS 7.0 introduced "Managed App Configuration", that makes it easy to support configuration of an enterprise application by a variety of MDM solutions.

Is there a similar thing in Android? 
I noticed that in the Google For Work help section it is mentioned, but for the life of me, I could not find how to implement support for it.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6257696?hl=en&ref_topic=6137710

Should I implement "App Restrictions" as mentioned here?
If so, how can I support devices with Android versions prior to Lollipop?
http://www.appconfigforenterprise.org/dev-center.html

Comment: did you implemented this? If so, how are you getting the details from Air watch console in android application. Could you please help me on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112688/integrating-air-watch-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a website called [AppConfig](https://www.appconfig.org/android/). It explains how it works both in Android and iOS and describes the Development steps. I'm also new to this field, but yes, as far as I know you need to implement App Restrictions.

And [here](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/index.html) is the Developer Training from Google, about Android for Work.

Comment: Can you please look into this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112688/integrating-air-watch-android-studio